# Inversify auto-typing @inject

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs

In typescript code using inversify I often see explicit type information in places where pure typescript would not need it because it can be inferred.

The following example contains two references to `B`, one through `TYPES.B` and then again in the explicit typing `b: B`.

```
@injectable()
class B {}

container.bind(TYPES.B).to(B).inSingletonScope();

@injectable()
class A {
  constructor(@inject(TYPES.B) private b: B) {}
}
```

In pure typescript without the (niceties that injection brings) you could write similar code that only contains one reference to `B` without any chance for a mix-up:

```
class B {}

class A {
  private b = new B();
}
```

Does someone know a clever typescript trick that tells the type checker what `@inject(TYPES.B)` will produce so that bugs with wrong typings can be caught?

Comment: Those aren't extra type annotations. In the  expression `@inject(TYPES.B)`,  `TYPES.B` is not a type but I value. This is so evident from the fact that it is used in a value position not a type position. The value `TYPES.B` is the key the injector uses to look up the value for the parameter

Comment: yes, but the `: B` in that same line only exists because typescript cannot infer what `@inject(TYPES.B)` will do. If by mistake I add `: C`, typescript will not complain:
`constructor(@inject(TYPES.B) private b: C) {}`

Comment: That's correct, it's impossible for there to be such inference.

Comment: Well, we could wrap the tokens in typed definitions. I think the only blocker then is in typescript https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43132